Why does shutil.copytree() and distutils.dir_util.copy_tree() copy the contents of a source directory, not the directory itself?
I'm using On python 3.11 on Windows. I have a directory "comfyui\js" I want to copy the directory "js", from" comfyui" to a destination "T:\temp" so that the result is "T:\temp\js".
I have found that bothdistutils.dir_util.copy_tree("comfyui/js","T:/temp") and shutil.copytree("comfyui/js","T:/temp") copy the contents under "comfyui\js" into "T:\tmp" but do not create "T:\tmp\js".
copy_tree("L:/comfyui/js", "T:/temp")
['T:/temp\\green_diamond_00.png', 'T:/temp\\green_pixel_00.png', 'T:/temp\\green_square_8x8.png', 'T:/temp\\image_transceiver_controller.js', 'T:/temp\\magic_lamp_160x86.png', 'T:/temp\\pict_cha_mockup.html']

I'm pretty sure I can work around this with something like:
            if os.path.isdir(src_path):
            copy_tree(src_path, f"{dest_dir}/{src_path.name}")

But this is not what I expected from reading the docs on both functions, and I don't get why I have to treat directories differently from files.

The answer to "why" is "because that is what they are designed and documented to do", from the documentation: "The end result of the copy is that every file in src is copied to dst, and directories under src are recursively copied to dst."  Are you asking "How can I copy a single folder with its contents, instead of just its contents?"

Can you explain why you wouldn't just shutil.copytree("comfyui/js","T:/temp/js"? (and remove T:/temp/js prior to that, if it already exists)  If you want to copy new or updated files into an existing folder (leaving files that don't exist in the source), you'll have to do a bit more work, but that goes beyond the question, I think.

"why I have to treat directories differently from files" - because when a file is copied into a directory, there's no doubt about what is intended. But when a directory is copied into a directory, there's ambiguity about copy the directory itself, or its contents into the other directory. A choice has to be made about how to resolve that ambiguity.
